# Program doesn't work on every machine, and where it works depends on the Oracle client version installed. Why?

Tags: .net, oracle

I reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll in my project. It works fine on my computer. When it is transferred to another colleague's computer, it no longer works, the error being:

```
    The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

even if the dll is copied into the Application directory. So I compiled it with a different version of the dll, and it still worked on my computer, it now also worked on my colleague's computer, but didn't work on the client's server.

I've googled this a lot and all the solutions I've found are bad - they involve installing software on the machine - my application needs to work on any machine regardless of what may or may not be installed there. Is there a way to make this work universally?

Edit: It is even acceptable if Oracle client is required to be installed. But it is not acceptable to be version-picky. I can pick whatever version of the DLL I want and use it, I want a version that will always work everywhere. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Surprisingly, I never ran into this problem with System.Data.OracleClient, which is very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to managed Oracle.DataAccess.dll, you also need to copy the **native** OCI DLLs to the application's dir. The easiest way to obtain these DLLs is through Oracle [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).

Just be careful to use the right "bitness" (32-bit DLLs for 'x86' configuration, 64-bit DLLs for 'x64' configuration and whatever bitness matches the target machine for the 'Any CPU' configuration).

Comment: Thanks. If we assume every target machine will have Oracle Client installed, but an arbitrary version, is it possible to somehow avoid having to copy all these files? I'm asking because I have a different app that uses System.Data.OracleClient and I have never seen it not work somewhere regardless of OC version, it even works regardless of "bitness", and I don't have to pack even a single oracle-related DLL with it. Is this really not possible with Oracle.DataAccess? I don't mind copying one file, but 20+ mb is a bit much in this specific case...

Comment: @svinja If you could somehow check the installed Oracle Client version, then I suppose you could skip copying the files when the right files are already installed. I'm not sure how to perform this check though. This would also be problematic in case user uninstalls or installs a different version of the Oracle Client _after_ your application is installed. Space and bandwidth are cheap these days, I recommend you simply do the copy.

Comment: I have switched to using System.Data.OracleClient and no longer need any DLLs and it works on all three machines even though they have different OCs. This is not really a "solution", but it does the job temporarily. I can't have an installation or anything like that, unfortunately, it must be as simple as possible as this particular project is more of a utility invoked by other applications than a user application. So it must be possible to easily pack it with another application. However as S.D.OC is no longer being supported I hope I will find a "real" solution eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your application to use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html).  Your application would need to install the Basic or Basic Lite Instant Client package along with the ODAC package and configure a couple of environment variables as part of your installation process.